# Stop AspNet Identity storing email address after validation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have a serivce that fetches a list of users from a legacy system and synchronises my AspNet Identity database. I’ve a problem when updating a user’s email address with `UserManager.SetEmail(string userId, string email)` and the validation fails. The user object in the `UserStore` retains the value of the invalid email address. I stop processing that user and skip to the next user in my list. Later when my service finds a new user to create, I use `UserManager.Create(ApplicationUser user)` and the database is updated with all outstanding changes including the invalid email address of the existing user.

Is there a way to stop the invalid email address being persisted? Is this a bug or am I just not using it correctly? Should I just manually take a backup of every object before any update and revert all values if the IdentityResult has an error?

```
//get LegacyUsers
foreach (AppUser appUser in LegacyUsers){
    var user = UserManager.FindByName(appUser.userName);
    if (user != null){
        If (!user.Email.Equals(appUser.Email)){
            var result = UserManager.setEmail(user.Id, appUser.Email)
            if (!result.Succeeded){
                //user object still has new value of email despite error, but not yet persisted to DB.
                Log.Error(…);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ApplicationUser newUser = new ApplicationUser{
            UserName = appUser.userName,
            //etc
        }
        var result = UserManager.Create(newUser);  //DB updates first user with new email aswell as inserting this new user 
        if (!result.Succeeded){
            Log.Error(…);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using version 2.2.1.40403 of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because EF keeps track of models and updates all of the modified objects when `SaveChanges()` method is called by `UserManager.Create()` method. You could easily detach the user which has invalid email from the  `DbContext` like this:

```
// first get DbContext from the Owin.
var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

foreach (AppUser appUser in LegacyUsers){
    var user = UserManager.FindByName(appUser.userName);
    if (user != null){
        If (!user.Email.Equals(appUser.Email)){
            var result = UserManager.setEmail(user.Id, appUser.Email)
            if (!result.Succeeded){                
                Log.Error(…);
                // detach the user then proceed to the next one 
                context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        // rest of the code
    }
}
```